# How to return database results in a fair manner - MySQL , PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, search

I'm creating a function that retrieves records based on several different fields and then stores those records so we can query them later.

When querying the records, we're selecting a record to be used elsewhere if it matches the requirements of another set of fields/criteria.

For example:

Returning employee records so that one of them can be selected for a new position (management maybe?) based on fields such as skill set, location, and so on...

**The problem**

Say I loop through these stored records (in an array or something similar) and I check if the first employee in the array is suitable for the position, then find out they are, so then add them to the position, I'm neglecting the other x amount of employees that have been stored. I feel like this would be an issue because it might turn out that the order in which someone is stored might determine the likelyhood they are chosen for the position.

I thought this might be solved by creating a sorting function to sort the stored records based on the employers preferences (location, salary, availability,...), although I'm not sure how to implement this.

I'm wondering if there is any built in MySQL functions that would help sort the records based on something?

This might be something I might have to figure out on my own, but I thought I'd ask just in case there was anything useful I could use.

I hope the question was clear. If not, please comment below.

Comment: It is not a function that sort records, it is the `order by` clause of a select statement. You need to come up with your own sorting criteria, you can't expect us to do that for you. Speak with your HR team because designing the sorting is an HR task.

Comment: I'm not expecting someone to make me an algorithm. I'm merely asking for some insight and potentially good starting points to tackle this potentially long task

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking out loud - won't sorting create the same issue you are trying to avoid - unless you can come up with a weighted score...

```
create table as employees_to_consider as
select e.*, 
         availability_score*availablity_factor
       + salary_score*salary_factor
       + location_score*location_factor as weighted_score
from employees e
where -- whatever your criteria is for selection here
order by weighted_score
```

The real task is deciding how to determine the score for each factor and what the appropriate weight should be.

For example, salary score can be determined by taking the ratio of what the employee is willing to work for by the target.  If they match, it can be scored as 50.  The number can be increased by the amount the employee is willing to work under the target and decreased by an amount they are over.  Salary is pretty important so the factor might be 33%.

Similarly, if the employee lives with 15 minutes, then they can be scored at 75, within 30 at 50, over 30 25.  Location is not as important as salary so it is scored at 10%.

Hopefully, you will be able to assign meaningful scores and factors to each measure.